# How to insert an element into an Array?

Tags: java, arrays, static-methods

I spent a few hours on trying to figure this out, but I can't seem to. I tried multiple different things and methods to correct it then I looked online on multiple sites and I couldn't find one that doesn't involve Array Lists. I don't want to use Array List for this. When I do it's either for C, C++, JavaScript or something else. Lessons online on inserting Arrays often involve Array Lists, or through the main method which isn't my goal.

I want to insert the element of the new array in the 3rd position, without removing the one currently there to output `[1, 2, 3, 4]`

```
import java.util.Arrays;
public class MainArrays {
  public static int[] add(int[] arr, int val) {
      int[] newArray = Arrays.copyOf(arr, arr.length + 1);
      newArray[arr.length] = val;
      return newArray;
   }
   public static int[] del(int[] arr) {
      return Arrays.copyOf(arr, arr.length - 1);
   }
   public static int[] ins(int[] a, int pos, int num) {
    int[] result = new int[arr.length];
    for(int i = 0; i < pos; i++)
        result[i] = a[i];
    result[pos] = num;
    for(int i = pos + 1; i < a.length; i++)
        result[i] = a[i - 1];
    return result;
    }
   
  

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      int[] a = { 1, 2, 4 };
      System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a));
      a = add(a, 7);
      System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a));
      a = del(a);
      System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a));
      a = ins(a);
      System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a));
     
   }
}
```

Terminal before insert method

```
/usr/bin/env /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-18.0.1.1.jdk/Contents/Home/
bin/java -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=n,suspend=y,address=localhost:60812 --enable-preview -XX:+Sho
wCodeDetailsInExceptionMessages -cp /private/var/folders/hx/s_5smg5s6510w9_szj6xk8200000gn/T/vscodesws_37f78/jdt
_ws/jdt.ls-java-project/bin MainArrays 
[1, 2, 4]
[1, 2, 4, 7]
[1, 2, 4]
```

Terminal after insert

```
/usr/bin/env /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-18.0.1.1.jdk/Contents/Home/
bin/java -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=n,suspend=y,address=localhost:60922 --enable-preview -XX:+Sho
wCodeDetailsInExceptionMessages -cp /private/var/folders/hx/s_5smg5s6510w9_szj6xk8200000gn/T/vscodesws_37f78/jdt
_ws/jdt.ls-java-project/bin MainArrays 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
        The method ins(int[], int, int) in the type MainArrays is not applicable for the arguments (int[])

        at MainArrays.main(MainArrays.java:30)
```

Problems Tab

```
MainArrays.java is a non-project file, only syntax errors are reported.
```

Comment: The error clearly states: that "ins" method is expecting (int[], int, int) arguments and in your code you are calling "ins" method with just int[].. "a = ins(a);" is the culprit.

Comment: This code will not compile since there is no `arr` in `ins` to get `arr.length` from. If there were, it wouldn't work anyway, since the length is one too small. You need to add one to the length to make room for the new value.

Comment: There are currently two errors in your code.

The first error is that you need to change `int[] result = new int[arr.length];` in your `ins(int[], int, int)` method to `int[] result = new int[a.length];`. The reason you need to do this is because there is no variable named `arr`.

The second error is in your main method. You are attempting to call your `ins(int[], int, int)` method without actually passing in the two additional arguments needed. The line of code I am talking about is `a = ins(a);`.

Comment: @Moraban Thanks it works but how do I keep the ```1,2,3,4``` Because the 4 was removed for 3.

Answer (score 0):

When you want to add to your int[] Array, you would of course need to supply the particular integer value you want to add, like you do with your `add()` method. This needs to work the same for when you delete (`del()`) from the array or insert (`ins()') values into the array. You would need to inform the method which array index to delete and you would need to inform the 'ins()` method at what index to insert a value and what the value will be to insert.

You can't just have: `arr = del(arr);`. Well...you can and the code below can do this but it basically deletes the entire array in this situation. Normally you would want to supply the index value for the array element you want to delete. If you want to delete the value **3** from your array then you would want to delete the element at **index 2**, so, the call would be `arr = del(arr, 2);`, the **3** would end up being deleted.

The same applies to the `ins()` method. You know this stuff! You can't just have: `arr = ins(arr);`. You need something like: `arr = ins(arr, 2, 65);` - insert the number **65** at index **2** within he supplied array **arr**).

Below are working examples of `add()`, `del()`, and `ins()` methods. Please read the comments in code (they're helpful):

```
 /**
 * Add one or more integer element values to the end of the supplied int[] 
 * Array.
 * <p>
 * @param arr (int[] Array) The int[] array to add one or more values to.
 * <p>
 * @param valueArgs (int varArgs) Single or multiple values can be added to 
 * the array. You can supply as many values as you like to be added as long 
 * as they are delimited with a comma or supplied within an int[] array. Here 
 * are some examples how this method can be used:<pre>
 * <code>
 * 
 *     array = add(array, 7);            // Adds 7 to the end of the Array.
 *     array = add(array, 7, 9, 11, 13); // Adds 7,9,11, and 13 to the end of the Array.
 *     
 *     int[] ary = {7, 9, 11, 13};       // Adds 7,9,11, and 13 to the end of the Array.
 *     array = add(array, ary);</code></pre>
 * 
 * @return (int[] Array)
 */
public static int[] add(int[] arr, int... valueArgs) {
    int[] newArray = Arrays.copyOf(arr, arr.length + valueArgs.length);
    int indexCounter = 0;
    for (int i = arr.length; i < newArray.length; i++) {
        newArray[i] = valueArgs[indexCounter];
        indexCounter++;
    }
    return newArray;
}

/**
 * Deletes elements within the supplied int[] Array.
 * <p>
 * @param arr (int[] Array) The int[] array to delete elements from.
 * <p>
 * @param indexArgs (int varArgs) Supplied array index values are expected 
 * here either singularly, multiple index values (comma delimited) or an
 * int[] array where the elements of that array contain the index values 
 * that need to be deleted from the supplied int[] array. Examples would be: <pre>
 * 
 * <code>   arr = del(arr);              // Delete entire arr (array becomes null).
 *    arr = del(arr, 2);           // Delete the element at index 2 from arr.
 *    arr = del(arr, 2, 4, 5);     // Delete elements at index 2, 4, and 5 from arr.
 * 
 *    int[] idxArray = {2, 4, 5};  // Delete elements at index 2, 4, and 5 from arr.
 *    arr = del(arr, idxArray)</code></pre>
 * 
 * @return (int[] Array) The int[] array containing all elements which were not 
 * not deleted. 
*/
public static int[] del(int[] arr, int... indexArgs) {
    if (indexArgs.length == 0) {
        return null;
    }
    int[] newArray = new int[arr.length - indexArgs.length];
    boolean skipIt;
    int indexCounter = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        skipIt = false;
        for (int idx : indexArgs) {
            if (i == idx) {
                skipIt = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!skipIt) {
            newArray[indexCounter] = arr[i];
            indexCounter++;
        }
               
    }
    return newArray;
}

/**
 * Inserts an integer value (num) into the supplied int[] array (arr) at the 
 * supplied index value (pos).
 * <p>
 * @param arr (int[] Array) The int[] Array to insert an integer value into.
 * <p>
 * @param pos (int) The index value where the supplied integer value (num) is 
 * to be inserted.
 * <p>
 * @param num (int) the integer value to be inserted into the supplied array.
 * <p>
 * @return (int[] Array) The new Array with the supplied value inserted.
 */
public static int[] ins(int[] arr, int pos, int num) {
    /* If the supplied position is greater than the number
       of elements within the supplied array then modify the
       poaition value so to insert num to the end of the array. */
    if (pos > arr.length) {
        pos = arr.length;
    }
    
    int[] newArray = new int[arr.length + 1]; // Add 1 element to the new array for the insertion.
    int idxCounter = 0;  // Counter to handle indexing for newArray
    for (int i = 0; i < newArray.length; i++) {
        if (i == pos) {
            newArray[idxCounter] = num;
            idxCounter++;
            /* Make sure i is within bounds for arr[]. This is for
               inserting at end of newArray.               */
            if (i < arr.length) {
                newArray[idxCounter] = arr[i];
                idxCounter++;
            }
        }
        else {
            /* This is for when we inserted at beginnig of newArray
               and now we might go overbounds at the end. After all, 
               newArray (which we are iterating) contains one more 
               element than arr[].                   */
            if (i < arr.length) {
                newArray[idxCounter] = arr[i];
                idxCounter++;
            }
        }
    }
    return newArray;
}
```

To use these methods you might do something like this:

```
int[] a = {1, 2, 4};
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a));

a = add(a, 7, 9, 11);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a));

a = del(a, 1,2,3);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a));

a = ins(a, 2, 13);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a));
```

The console window output should look something like this:

```
[1, 2, 4]
[1, 2, 4, 7, 9, 11]
[1, 9, 11]
[1, 9, 13, 11]
```